# Am I using notify incorrectly java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public synchronized void run(){
       while(running){
         if(!paused){
                //synchronized(CardGame.playingDeckArray){
                    playGame();
                    if ( playerNumber == CardGame.playingDeckArray.length ){
                        notifyAll();
                    }else{ 
                    try{
                        wait();
                    }catch( InterruptedException e){
                }
            }
           // }
         }
       }
    }


private void playGame(){
            switch(strategyChosen){
                case 1 : playStratOne();
                break;
                case 2 : playStratTwo();
                break;
            }
    }


private void playStratTwo(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep( 1000*playerNumber );
        }catch( InterruptedException e ){
        }

            int index = 0;
            System.out.println( getPlayerName() + " discards a " + hand[index].getCardValue() + " to deck " + playerNumber );
            Logger.addToOutput( getPlayerName(), getPlayerName() + " discards a " + hand[index].getCardValue() + " to deck " + playerNumber + "\n");
            CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber-1].add( new Card( getHandValue(hand[index])));

            for( int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++){
                if ( index == hand.length-1 ){
                    hand[index] = new Card(0);
                }else{
                    hand[index] = hand[index+1];
                    index++;
                }
            }

            if ( playerNumber == 1){
                System.out.println( getPlayerName() + " draws a " + ((CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber + CardGame.playersNum - 2].peek()).getCardValue()) + " from deck " + ( CardGame.playersNum ) );
                Logger.addToOutput( getPlayerName(), getPlayerName() + " draws a " + ((CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber + CardGame.playersNum - 2].peek()).getCardValue()) + " from deck " + ( CardGame.playersNum ) + "\n" );
                hand[index] = CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber + CardGame.playersNum - 2].poll();
            }else{
                System.out.println( getPlayerName() + " draws a " + (( CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber - 2].peek()).getCardValue())  + " from deck " + ( playerNumber - 1 ) );
                Logger.addToOutput( getPlayerName(), getPlayerName() + " draws a " + (( CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber - 2].peek()).getCardValue())  + " from deck " + ( playerNumber - 1 ) + "\n" );
                hand[index] = CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber - 2].poll();
            }
            Logger.addToOutput( getPlayerName(), getHand() );

            System.out.println( getPlayerName()+ "'s hand is " );
            seeHand();

            checkWinner();
        }
```

When i run my program with this strategy, the programs works properly until it gets to the last player thread, which does its actions but doesnt seem to wake up the other threads. have i used the notifyAll() method incorrectly because the debugger shows the other threads to still be waiting. Help would be appreciated.

```
public void run(){
       synchronized(CardGame.playingDeckArray){
       while(running){
         if(!paused){
             playGame();
                    if ( playerNumber == CardGame.playingDeckArray.length ){
                       CardGame.playingDeckArray.notifyAll();
                    } else{
                    try{        
                        while(playerNumber != CardGame.playingDeckArray.length){
                        CardGame.playingDeckArray.wait();
                    }
                    }catch( InterruptedException e){
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT

I tried this alternate run method but what happens is that the first thread does its actions, and then there is a pause and then the final thread does its actions just like before.

```
Player 1's hand is currently
10
6
6
5
2
Player 2's hand is currently
4
9
6
6
3
Player 3's hand is currently
4
6
5
6
6
Player 4's hand is currently
6
8
7
9
9
Player 5's hand is currently
9
1
5
3
4
Player 1 discards a 10 to deck 1
Player 1 draws a 5 from deck 5
Player 1's hand is 
6
6
5
2
5
Player 5 discards a 9 to deck 5
Player 5 draws a 5 from deck 4
Player 5's hand is 
1
5
3
4
5
Player 5 discards a 1 to deck 5
Player 5 draws a 3 from deck 4
Player 5's hand is 
5
3
4
5
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a problem with lost notifications. Replace your wait code with something like that:

```
while(playerNumber != CardGame.playingDeckArray.length)
  wait();
```

Another thing:

How are you using your code? Have you implemented a `Runnable` that you share among the threads you spawn? Since you call `notifyAll()` and `wait()` directly on the `Runnable` you would have to do that. If not, you have to share a lock object among the threads!

An example:

```
// the monitor object that is shared among all the threads
final Object monitor = new Object();

// this variable has to be shared, is synchronized using the monitor object.
// you could also synchronize on this object instead of the separate monitor object.
final CardGamestate = ...

// ...
Player p = new Player(monitor);
// start the player, runs in a different thread
p.startPlaying();
```

assuming the code you posted is in the `Player` class, you need to synchronize on the monitor that is shared!

Maybe something like the following to wait:

```
synchronized(monitor) {
  // wait until condition is valid
  while(playerNumber != CardGame.playingDeckArray.length)
    monitor.wait();
}
```

and to wake up:

```
synchronized(monitor) {
  // playerNumber == CardGame.playingDeckArray.length has to evaluate `true`
  // finally notify the waiting thread(s)
  monitor.notifyAll(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `wait` and `notify` functions work on the object's monitor. This means that if you call `obj1.wait()`, and in a different thread `obj2.notifyAll()`, the thread waiting on `obj1` will *not* be woken up.

Your code is not complete, but it appears that you are calling the functions on different object instances, therefore they will not be able to wake each other up.

Comment: all the threads are accesing the same array in the CardGame class, i tried changing the code CardGame.playingDeckArray.notifyAll(), but i just get illegalmonitorexcpetiions